# EXCEL VBA WorksheetFunction.CountIf() in a SELECT CASE

Tags: excel, vba, select, case

I know that it is possible to use `If` statement but out of curiosity, as mentioned in the title, is it possible to use `SELECT` statement to do something as **BOLDED** below? I've submitted my whole `Sub` as below for better understanding:

Sub addNewCust_Click()

```
Dim response As String

response = Application.InputBox(prompt:="", Title:="New customer name", Type:=2)

Select Case response
Case False
    Exit Sub

'Check if response is not an empty value AND record found in "CustomerList"
```

> **Case Is <> "" & WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("CustomerList").Range("B:B"), response) > 0**

```
    MsgBox "'" & response & "' already exists on this sheet."
    Call addNewCust_Click

'Check if response is not an empty value and record is not found in "Customerlist"
```

> **Case Is <> "" & WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("CustomerList").Range("B:B"), response) < 1**

```
    Sheets("CustomerList").Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = response
    MsgBox "'" & response & "' successfully entered!"**

Case Else
        MsgBox "Field is empty!"
        Call addNewCust_Click

End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
Sub addNewCust_Click()
    Dim response As String

    response = Application.InputBox(prompt:="", Title:="New customer name", Type:=2)

    Select Case response
    Case False: Exit Sub    
    'Check if response is not an empty value AND record found in "CustomerList"
    Case Is <> ""
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("CustomerList").Range("B:B"), response) > 0 Then
            MsgBox "'" & response & "' already exists on this sheet."
            Call addNewCust_Click
        Else
            Sheets("CustomerList").Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = response
            MsgBox "'" & response & "' successfully entered!"
        End If
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Field is empty!"
        Call addNewCust_Click
    End Select
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP (From Comments)**

`Select Case` is considered to be faster than `If-Endif` but for such a small scenario, the efficiency comparison is futile. What is more important is how you write the code

Below is another way. I love this way as things are broken down into smaller parts and everything is declared properly. I am not touching error handling below. See this for detailed [analysis](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/08/01/to-err-is-human/).

The below method is useful because

1. when you are looking at your code (say maybe after an year) and you know exactly what is happening since the code is commented.
2. Easy to maintain the code. For example if the Sheet name changes then you have to change it only at one place. The alternative is to also use `Codenames`
3. You can use the same code across all Excel platforms. If you hardcode your range, Ex: `Range("B1048576")` then the above code will not work in Excel 2003.

*Sample Code*

```
Sub addNewCust_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim response

    '~~> Set the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CustomerList")

    With ws
        Do
            '~~> Get user response
            response = Application.InputBox(prompt:="", Title:="New customer name", Type:=2)

            Select Case response
                Case False: Exit Sub    '<~~ If user presses cancel or closes using 'X'
                Case "": MsgBox "Field is empty!" '<~~ If user enters a blank entry
                Case Else
                    '~~> Check if the entry exists
                    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("B:B"), response) > 0 Then
                        MsgBox "'" & response & "' already exists on this sheet."
                    Else
                        '~~> Get last Row
                        Lrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                        '~~> Add the new entry
                        .Range("B" & Lrow).Value = response
                        MsgBox "'" & response & "' successfully entered!"
                        Exit Do 'OR Exit Sub (As Applicable)
                    End If
            End Select
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works like a charm! And by the way do you think this section of code is more efficient? `If` statement in `SELECT` statement.

Comment: I actually would do this in a slightly different way :)

Comment: May I adhere your method? And are they comparable in terms of performance?

Comment: I wouldn't use `Call addNewCust_Click` twice, I would rather use a Do Loop and declare `response` as a variant :)

Comment: Using loop will be slower isn't it?

Comment: The general idea is that loops are slower but then it depends on how you use it. By using `Call addNewCust_Click`, you are also looping. isn't it? :)

Comment: Also I wouldn't use hardcoded values like `B1048576`... Let me update the above post with the code that I might have alternatively tried.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough explanation Sid! I've also read your website and credit your effort.